# Nativescript - getting rid of a ios build warning

Tags: nativescript

When I build my app for ios - I'm getting a bunch of warnings similar to below.

Where do I set this IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET variable?

```
[snipped]/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'Toast' from project 'Pods')
```

Answer (score 0):

This configuration is applied in `App_Resources/iOS/build.xcconfig`. It might also be the case that this warning is coming from one of your dependencies, Toast I'm assuming.